# How do I remove documents after search results using Node.js Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database

```
        AAAModel.find({'category' : category})
          .skip(100)
          .sort({date: 'desc'})
          .exec(function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            next(err);
          }
          if (result) {
            result.remove();
          }
        });
```

the above doesn't work.
I would like to remove the 100 Items or more of the search results, what should I do?

Comment: are you using mongoose to access data?

Comment: yes. I choose mongoose.

Answer (score 2):

You could try one of this approach:

```
Model.findOne({_id: 'specific_id'}, (err, doc) => {
    doc.remove((err) => {
        if (err) // handle err
    });
    // or simply use
    doc.remove();
});
```

or

```
Model.findOne({_id: 'specific_id'}).remove((err, doc) => {

});
```

or

```
Model.remove({_id: 'specific_id'}, (err, doc) => {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

```
 AAAModel.find(
               {'category' : category}, 
               { skip: 100,sort:{date: -1}}, 
               function(err, results) { 
                  if (err) {
                      next(err);
                  }
                  if (result) {
                      result.remove();
                  }
 });
```

Comment: how can I use remove method? I want to remove results after exec your query.

Comment: `results` do not have remove on them, instead use `results.forEach(r => r.remove())`

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem.
In fact in latest mongoose query has **remove** method. So, it theory it could work like this:

```
AAAModel.find({'category' : category})
  .skip(100)
  .sort({date: -1})
  .remove(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    next(err);
  }
  if (result) {
    console.log("Number of deleted records:" +  result);
  }
});
```

But in my case this code removed **all** records
So, the possible solution is

```
AAAModel.find({'category' : category})
  .select("_id")
  .skip(100)
  .sort({date: -1})
  .exec(function(err, idObjLst) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    var ids = idObjLst.map(function(idObj) { return idObj._id; });
    if (ids && ids.length > 0) {
    AAAModel.remove({_id: {$in: ids}}).exec(function(err, result) {
       console.log("Removed " + result + " elements");
     });
});
```

Could be quite *expensive* though.

Comment: Good idea, but `ids` will be an array of docs that look like `{_id: ObjectId}` so I think you'll also need to use `ids.map` to reshape `ids` into an array of ObjectIds before using it with `$in`.

Comment: JohnnyHK: you right of course, however, this code also works (probably due to specific of iteration process inside mongoose). I've tested with mongoose 3.8.22

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't work for me with 3.8.23 -- nothing is removed.

Comment: @JohnnyHK. That's strange. I've update mongoose to 3.8.24. And there is working example from my project. https://gist.github.com/loki256/4c3272aa00f179ec5ab4. Nevertheless, even if works it's wrong :)

Comment: answer was updated, according to @JohnnyHK's remarks.

Answer (score 0):

As we know, the parameter `results` is an array of documents in your `find` callback, not a single document. so you can iterate it and remove item one by one, despite this is not best way to remove documents for performance.

Actually, mongoose [Mode.remove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove) can be used to remove documents, but the query condition can not skip and sort until now.